# Indian Citizen/Canadian Permanent Resident never gets TSA Pre despite Nexus card

Tags: nexus, tsa-precheck

I am an Indian citizen who resides in Canada as a Permanent Resident. I have a Nexus card. I was told by the officers during my interview that I would get Global Entry and TSA pre benefits. I do get Global entry but I never get the TSA Pre on my boarding pass. I have travelled in US using American Airlines and Air Canada (3 trips). Each time I have ensured that the reservation has my Nexus number as KTN.

Am I missing something? Will I get TSA pre when I become a Canadian citizen?

My Nexus card has my middle name in the given name and in the Airlines I write my middle name in the Middle Name box for ticket booking and in the Given Name box for their document verification section.

My wife doesnt have a middle name anywhere and she also never gets TSA Pre, even when she travels without me.

Comment: Have you correctly added your Known Traveler Number to each reservation?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan yes, in fact thats how i am able to checkin online. Without it, a gate agent would need to verify my US visa.

Comment: While it looks like Michael has found the correct reason that you need to be a Canadian citizen, it could be the mix-up in names. Have you ever tried setting up your flight ticket with your first/middle names swapped so they match your nexus card?

Comment: @mkennedy no harm in trying i suppose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [DHS Trusted Traveler Programs](https://ttp.cbp.dhs.gov/) web site, NEXUS card holders get TSA Pre benefits if they are US citizens, US permanent residents or Canadian citizens.

> Access to TSA Pre✓® expedited security lanes at airports within the U.S. and U.S territories for U.S. Citizens, U.S. lawful permanent residents and Canadian citizens.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping this is outdated as agents told me otherwise. Also, its kinda ridiculous that Indian citizens who have global entry get TSA Pre benefits and I cant even apply to Global entry because I am a Canadian PR. Oh well, guess I will wait until I am a Canadian.

Comment: You'd almost think that this is a government operation. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ry55--J4_VQ